# JavaFX set label text by css

Tags: java, javafx-8, javafx-css

I was wondering if by javafx-css it's possible to set label text.
On the official documentation i found a reference to

```
-fx-text: "whatever";
```

but isn't working, basically i'm searching for and equivalent of css3

```
content: "whatever";
```

specified here: [W3School](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_gen_content.asp)

Comment: What official documentation are you talking about? Neither the javadoc nor the CSS Reference Guide seem to contain anything like this...

Comment: @fabian I don't remember where i saw it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not possible in JavaFX and you can easily verify this by getting all the styleable properties from a `Label`:

```
Label label = new Label();
label.getCssMetaData().stream().map(CssMetaData::getProperty).sorted().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Which yields the following list (not including `-fx-text` or anything that allows you to set the content according to the [*CSS Reference Guide*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html)):

```
-fx-alignment
-fx-blend-mode
-fx-content-display
-fx-cursor
-fx-effect
-fx-ellipsis-string
-fx-focus-traversable
-fx-font
-fx-graphic
-fx-graphic-text-gap
-fx-label-padding
-fx-line-spacing
-fx-max-height
-fx-max-width
-fx-min-height
-fx-min-width
-fx-opacity
-fx-opaque-insets
-fx-padding
-fx-position-shape
-fx-pref-height
-fx-pref-width
-fx-region-background
-fx-region-border
-fx-rotate
-fx-scale-shape
-fx-scale-x
-fx-scale-y
-fx-scale-z
-fx-shape
-fx-skin
-fx-snap-to-pixel
-fx-text-alignment
-fx-text-fill
-fx-text-overrun
-fx-translate-x
-fx-translate-y
-fx-translate-z
-fx-underline
-fx-wrap-text
visibility
```